# Regex contains not [str] (or part of [str]) followed by str2

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I would like to create a regex that when looking through code will able to find `.run` which is **not** preceded by `Application`.

I have tried to create the following regex -

```
(?=(?:(?!application))).\.run
```

But if I test it on `application.run(...)` it matches `n.run`

I've no idea how to fix it.
Would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Which language? Are you looking to negate only when `application` **immediately precedes** `.run` or when it's placed **anywhere before** `.run`?

Comment: Are you trying to do a substitution?

Comment: I'm doing it in Python and I'm not trying to identify substitutions, simply find those strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
(?<!application)\.run
```

https://regex101.com/r/5CJJKj/4/